# Android mediarecorder stop called in an invalid state : 4

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Hi all i'm creating a call recording app ,
When I'm trying to stop call recording the Debug Console in java says that :
"MediaRecorder stop called in an invalid state : 4"
im google a lot but i can't find nothing can help me !
im already using RECORD_AUDIO and WRITE_EXTRENAL_STORAGE permissions !
Here is some part of my code :

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/callrec/";
        final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path+"/TEST00000000011110.M4A");
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {

        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            isPhoneCalling = true;
            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            if (isPhoneCalling) {
                try {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                isPhoneCalling = false;
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're creating a new `MediaRecorder` object each time `onCallStateChanged` is called (i.e. the `MediaRecorder` you're trying to stop isn't the one you started).

Comment: @Michael i tried to create MediaRecorder in the : public class Main extends Activity , but for example it says the recorder.setAudioSource could not be found and underline it and think this is an error ! PLZ HELP ME!

Comment: My problem Not solved PLZ HELP ME !