# MediaRecorder : stop called in invalid state : 4

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a call recording app, when I'm trying to stop call recording the Debug Console in java says that: "MediaRecorder stop called in an invalid state : 4" I've Googled a lot but I can't find anything that can help me! I'm already using `RECORD_AUDIO` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions! Here is part of my code:

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/callrec/";
        final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path+"/TEST00000000011110.M4A");
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {

        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            isPhoneCalling = true;
            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            if (isPhoneCalling) {
                try {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my problem is not solved please some one help me ! :(

Comment: If you find [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891030/android-mediarecorder-stop-called-in-an-invalid-state-4) is not being answered please don't just re-ask it, edit the original question to clarify it and show your continued efforts to solve the problem yourself. Also; a word to the wise; text speak like "PLZ" and WRITING IN ALL CAPS rarely goes down well

Answer (score -4):

finally i found a way to fix my problem !
i created a :
public void Recorder()
in my class and when i want to record audio call it
also i created a function for stop recording !
i hope this work for you !
and also this MediaRecorder API works good on android 2.3.3 to 4.3 !